# How can a PMML reader interpret the predict value's type?

Tags: machine-learning, pmml

Hi I have a PMML generated for a logistic regression model using R as follows. Only the first part of the pmml is shown here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PMML version="4.2" xmlns="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dmg.org/PMML-4_2 http://www.dmg.org/v4-2/pmml-4-2.xsd">
 <Header copyright="Copyright (c) 2015 Upeksha" description="Generalized Linear Regression Model">
  <Extension name="user" value="Upeksha" extender="Rattle/PMML"/>
  <Application name="Rattle/PMML" version="1.4"/>
  <Timestamp>2015-12-02 08:41:27</Timestamp>
 </Header>
 <DataDictionary numberOfFields="11">
  <DataField name="ResponseAccountName" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="RegionCat" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
   <Value value="ROW"/>
   <Value value="EUROPE"/>
   <Value value="NAM"/>
  </DataField>
  <DataField name="TitleCat" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
   <Value value="1"/>
   <Value value="2"/>
   <Value value="3"/>
   <Value value="4"/>
  </DataField>
  <DataField name="RLMaxTitle" optype="categorical" dataType="string">
   <Value value="1"/>
   <Value value="2"/>
   <Value value="3"/>
   <Value value="4"/>
  </DataField>
  <DataField name="Act1_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Act2_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Act3_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Act4_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Act5_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="Act6_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
  <DataField name="AccntAct_rate" optype="continuous" dataType="double"/>
 </DataDictionary>
 <GeneralRegressionModel modelName="Logistic_Regression" modelType="generalizedLinear" functionName="regression" algorithmName="glm" distribution="binomial" linkFunction="logit">
  <MiningSchema>
   <MiningField name="ResponseAccountName" usageType="predicted"/>
   <MiningField name="RegionCat" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="TitleCat" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="RLMaxTitle" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="Act1_rate" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="Act2_rate" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="Act3_rate" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="Act4_rate" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="Act5_rate" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="Act6_rate" usageType="active"/>
   <MiningField name="AccntAct_rate" usageType="active"/>
  </MiningSchema>
  <Output>
   <OutputField name="Predicted_ResponseAccountName" feature="predictedValue"/>
  </Output>
```

The OutputField dataType is not present here. How could a PMMl reader interpret it's type if so?

I checked the PMML spec and it says that dataType for OutputField is not always required. I am writing a pmml reader and I need to know how the interpretation is done for a pmml like this.

Answer (score 0):

The `dataType` and `optype` attributes are optional for the `OutputField` element, but any sane PMML producer should specify them anyway, as that would make the life much easier for PMML consumers.

If the `dataType` attribute is missing, then you can infer it based on the `feature` attribute of the `OutputField` element. In the current case, the value of the `feature` attribute is set to `predictedValue`, which means that the data type and the operational type will be "copied" from the `DataField` element that represents the target field of this model. Here, the target field (aka the predicted field) is called "ResponseAccountName", which means that the value of this `OutputField` element will be continuous double.